# How to remove item from relationship

Tags: laravel, api, post

I have a model with a hasOne relationship like this .

```
public function geoTournee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(GeoTournee::class, 'id_tournee','id_tournee');
    }
```

I have loaded the relationship and want to remove an item from the collection.

Here is the result after , i want  get only itineraire content and delete geo_tounee and other fields.

```
"geo_tournee": {
            "id_geo_tournee": 46,
            "itineraire": [
                {
                    "lat": 8000,
                    "lon": 3000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                },
                {
                    "lat": 8000,
                    "lon": 3000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                },
                {
                    "lat": 8000,
                    "lon": 3000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                },
                {
                    "lat": 5000,
                    "lon": 9000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                },
                {
                    "lat": 5000,
                    "lon": 9000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                },
                {
                    "lat": 5000,
                    "lon": 9000,
                    "date": "2020:04:21 16:58:23"
                }
            ],
            "id_tournee": 33,
            "created_at": "2020-04-23 18:10:32",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-23 22:26:53"
```

Any idea to do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it as below::

```
return $this->hasOne(GeoTournee::class, 'id_tournee','id_tournee')->select(['id_tournee', 'itineraire']);
```

You can also try eager loading:

```
$user = App\User::with(['geoTournee' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('itineraire');
}])->get();
```

Or below

```
App\User::with('geoTournee:itineraire')->get();
```

Comment: i get   null array off itineraire @Dipak Mewada with that

Comment: Ok @Dipak Mewada

Comment: there  return always geo_tournee field  @Dipak Mewada

Comment: i get the result i want with this  public static function formatItineraire(&$tournee){
        if($tournee['geo_tournee']){
            $tournee['itineraire'] = $tournee['geo_tournee']['itineraire'];
            unset($tournee['geo_tournee']);
        }
    }

Comment: @Moum i have updated my answer with few more solution pls. try that also.

Comment: i try @Dipak Mewada  your solution , but i get null .i use first() method at the end of eager loading may it the problem ?

Comment: Pls. try with get() method, one of this solution should definitively need to work, as per my understanding.

Comment: @Moum Great!! Glad to help you on your concern, if my answer solved your problem then please do up votes and mark it as accepted answer will be much appreciated!!.